# Left join to find nulls and non-matches

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query that returns null values (from the left join) and also returns different amounts with the `union` clause. It returns 3 rows, which is correct.

Is there a *non-complex* way to remove the `union` clause so that it returns nulls and mismatches in column `amount`?

```
declare @table1 table
(
    Id int,
    Amount decimal(8,2)
)
declare @table2 table
(
    Id int,
    Amount decimal(8,2)
)

insert into @table1
select 1, 1.50 union
select 2, 2.50 union
select 3, 3.50 union
select 4, 4.50 union
select 5, 5.50 


insert into @table2
select 1, 1.50 union
select 2, 2.75 union
select 3, 3.50


select t1.id, t1.amount, t2.id, t2.amount
from 
@table1 t1 left join @table2 t2 on
t1.Id = t2.Id
--and t1.Amount <> t2.amount
where 
t2.id is null

union

select t1.id, t1.amount, t2.id, t2.amount
from 
@table1 t1 inner join @table2 t2 on
t1.Id = t2.Id
where 
t1.Amount <> t2.amount
```

Result

```
id  amount  id  amount
2   2.50    2   2.75
4   4.50    NULL    NULL
5   5.50    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Using? Do you mean `union` not `using`?

Comment: you're right. I edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you're after something like:

```
select t1.id, t1.amount, t2.id, t2.amount
from @table1 t1  
left join @table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
where t1.Amount <> t2.amount or t2.id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try that because I thought that adding a condition to the right table would void the `left join` and turn it into an `inner join`. But you uses the `or` so that helps. Thanks again.